# data does not show in jquery mobile app

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, requirejs

I am new to jquery mobile and using it with Backbonejs and requirejs for the first time. I have two templates and adding contents to them. But the contents are not shown in the div tag where I want to show. It also does not show any error. All I see is empty area. **The code below does insert contents to templates but it does not show it to the user.**

Here is my code
movies.js file

```
define(['backbone', 'views/movie', 'jqm'], function (Backbone, MovieView) {
var Movies = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#movies',

    initialize: function () {
        App.Vent.on('init', this.renderAll, this);
    },

    renderAll: function () {
        this.$el.empty();
        this.collection.each(this.render, this);
    },

    render: function (movie) {
        //console.log(this.$el);
        var movieView = new MovieView({ model: movie });
        //console.log(this.$el.append(movieView.render().el));
        this.$el.append(movieView.render().el);
        console.log(this.$el);
        return this;
    }
});

return Movies;
});
```

here is movie.js file

```
define(['backbone', 'text!../../templates/movie.tpl'], function (Backbone, MovieTemplate) {
var Movie = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'ui-block-d',

    render: function () {
        //console.log(this.$el.html(_.template(MovieTemplate, this.model.toJSON())));
        this.$el.html(_.template(MovieTemplate, this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

return Movie;
});
```

how can I make it work? And please ask any question.

Comment: Is Movie the name of your model or your view? It looks like your passing in and using `MovieView`, but in your movie.js file your declaring a view named `Movie`

Comment: Just saw your edit, you probably need call the JQM refresh (or `trigger('create')` method on your dynamically added content.

Comment: how can I use JQM refresh here? Any example code please

Comment: I changed my code and added trigger like this `this.$el.append(movieView.render().el).trigger('create');` and also `this.$el.append(movieView.render().el).listview('refresh);`. But none of them are working.

Comment: Well basically many of the JQM widgets have a refresh method, for example if you were adding items to a list you would afterwards call `$('#myList').listview('refresh')`, or you can trigger a create event on your page which should initialize widgets that need initialization by for example calling `$('#myPage').trigger('create')`.

Comment: The `create` should be triggered on the page.

Comment: you mean on data-role="content"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24920/discussion-between-jack-and-x4ph4r)

Comment: Without JQM it does show data on the page